# Hibernate : No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 101

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, orm

I am facing issue while selecting records from datatabase,

Query :

```
 SELECT rownum as id, mm.metric_name, dm.aggregated_value_float,
 dm.created_timestamp, s.type, s.name as subelement_name FROM
 daily_metric dm, subelement s, metric_metadata mm  WHERE
 dm.subelement_id =s.subelement_id AND 
 TRUNC(dm.created_timestamp)='15-JAN-15' AND s.subelement_id =1456376 
 and dm.metric_metadata_id = mm.metric_metadata_id order by 1,2 desc
```

Code :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(query);
Object o =  query.uniqueResult();
```

Stack Trace

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 101
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:653)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType(JdbcResultMetadata.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2073)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1869)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:966)
```

I have tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930841/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-101-exception-while-using-named-query-in-hibe) but it showign `Hibernate.Timestamp`can not be resoved by compiler.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
```

Comment: It seams that you missed to define the database dialect in the hibernate config. I don't know your setup, direct hibernate or JPA? if Hibernate for example here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html or if jpa you have to place the same property keys to your persistence.xml as options.

Comment: you need to define hibernate dialect property according to your database.

Comment: plz show your hibernate.cfg.xml file where u have your properties for db connection

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: Hibernate version is `4.3.0.Final`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Object result = session.createSQLQuery(
        "SELECT " +
        "   rownum as id, " +
        "   mm.metric_name, " +
        "   dm.aggregated_value_float, " +
        "   dm.created_timestamp as dm_timestamp, " +
        "   s.type, " +
        "   s.name as subelement_name " +
        "FROM " +
        "   daily_metric dm, " +
        "   subelement s, " +
        "   metric_metadata mm " +
        "WHERE " +
        "   dm.subelement_id =s.subelement_id AND " +
        "   TRUNC(dm.created_timestamp)='15-JAN-15' AND " +
        "   s.subelement_id =1456376 AND " +
        "   dm.metric_metadata_id = mm.metric_metadata_id " +
        "ORDER BY 1,2 DESC")
.addScalar("dm_timestamp", TimestampType.INSTANCE)
.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: What about store procedures?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when selecting a single result via "getSingleResult()" from a table:

```
 BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal)query.getSingleResult();
```

It turned out that I had to explicitly cast the returned number within the select statement into a number:

```
 SELECT CAST(SUM(aggregated) as NUMBER) FROM ....
```